# Сортировка по размеру файла при рекурсивном обходе файлов

Tags: bash, сортировка

Как написать скрипт, который выводит список файлов, отсортированный по размеру данного каталога и всех его подкаталогов?

Вызов команды 
`ls -S -R -s` не помогает, так как он сортирует только в рамках одного каталога.

Answer (score 2):

Держите. Вам такой вариант подходит ?

```
sudo du -h | sort -h
```

Comment: надо что бы он выводил только имя, без полного пути. du же выводит полный путь. А как получить только имя? И как отсортировать в обратном порядке?

Comment: Вам выше предоставили ответ

Answer (score 2):

найти все файлы в указанном каталоге (и под-каталогах) можно, например, так (здесь и далее приведён пример вывода):

```
$ find путь/к/каталогу -type f
путь/к/каталогу/file1
путь/к/каталогу/dir/file2
```

вывести список в виде `размер-в-байтах имя-файла-без-пути-к-нему` можно, например, так:

```
$ find путь/к/каталогу -type f -printf '%s\t%f\n'
1000    file1
2000    file2
```

отсортировать полученный список по убыванию чисел:

```
$ find путь/к/каталогу -type f -printf '%s\t%f\n' | sort -rn
2000    file2
1000    file1
```

оставить в полученном списке только второй столбец (с именами файлов):

```
$ find путь/к/каталогу -type f -printf '%s\t%f\n' | sort -rn | cut -f 2
file2
file1
```